# Extract effort-success relation from INLA.surv model in R

Tags: r, weibull

We have made an inla.surv model which explains the success of capturing at least one animal based on Trap (type of trap, n=2) and location (4 per site) nested within site (n=5) as random variables. Start and end express the start and end day of each trapping experiment (scaled to one for the longest trapping experiment = 25 days) with one of the two trap types at a certain location and site. So the model looks like:

```
ms <- inla(
  inla.surv(Start, Event, End) ~ Trap + 
    f(Site, model = "iid", 
      hyper = list(theta = list(prior="pc.prec", param = c(0.1, 0.01)))
    ) + 
    f(Location, model = "iid", 
      hyper = list(theta = list(prior="pc.prec", param = c(0.1, 0.01)))
    ), 
  family = "weibullsurv",
  data = datatrap,
  control.family = list(variant = 0),
  control.compute = list(waic = TRUE, config = TRUE)
)
```

Now I would like to plot the chance to capture at least one animal (success) with one of these traps in function of the number of days the trap would be placed (effort). I found a similar code but for a exponential inla.surv model and it does not distinguish between a variable (in my case Trap). It is clear I can't use it but I show it here as it can help as inspiration or help to clarify what I want.

```
times <- seq(0.05, 1, by = 0.05)
alpha.marg <- ms$marginals.fixed[["(Intercept)"]]
S.inla <- mclapply(times, function(t){
  S.marg <- inla.tmarginal(function(x) {exp(- exp(x) * t)}, alpha.marg)
  S.stats <- inla.zmarginal(S.marg, silent = TRUE)
  return(unlist(S.stats[c("quant0.025", "mean", "quant0.975")]))
S.inla <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, S.inla))
plot(S.inla$mean~times)
lines(S.inla$quant0.025~times)
lines(S.inla$quant0.975~times)
```

This simple plot gives the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ybv0.png)